# What are unique job titles in academia called?

Tags: terminology

Occasionally a university gives a famous professor a job title individually designed for that one person only.  Thus:

- Donald Knuth is "Professor Emeritus of the Art of Computer Programming" at Stanford.
- Gian-Carlo Rota was "Professor of Applied Mathematics and Philosophy" at M.I.T., although he had an appointment only in the mathematics department.

Is there a common noun referring to such custom-designed job titles for rare famous professors?

**PS inspired by things written below:** This is not the same as an endowed chair or a distinguished professorship.  Some universities use the titled of "Distinguished Professor" and have rules saying only a limited number of professors can have that title; some universitites call the appointees "University Professors"; M.I.T. calls them "Institute Professors" (Isadore Singer in the math department is an Institute Professor). But with Distinguished Professors there is some codified rule saying these can exist and setting forth certain criteria for granting such a title.  Similarly for endowed chairs.  Knuth's title was based on the name of an influential and famous three-volume work on computer programming that Knuth had written; it would be absurd to promulgate a rule saying who might be appointed to this position in the future and according to which criteria, since it's a title that can fit only one person.  Nor could it have been contemplated in Rota's case that others might some day have that title; it was awarded only because of the unique circumstances of Rota's life.

Comment: Often these are called "chairs" or endowed chairs.

Comment: Named Chairs, for positions named after a person.

Comment: Rota's position looks like a generic full professor with appointments in two departments: (1) applied mathematics and (2) philosophy.  I often sign my official correspondence "Professor of Computer Science", but that just means I'm a full professor with an appointment in the computer science department; it's not an actual job title.

Comment: I'm not sure Rota is a good example of the phenomenon you are interested in. It sounds like he simply had a joint appointment in two departments. I know of many professors whose title is "Professor of Mathematics and X" because they have a joint appointment in math and X (usually a science or engineering discipline like CS, statistics, physics etc.). I wouldn't call this a "custom-designed" job title, but please clarify if you meant to include all such cases, which are quite common.

Comment: @StrongBad : I don't think what I'm referring to is the same as an endowed chair, although the incumbent may also have an endowed chair.

Comment: @DanRomik : You're mistaken: Rota had an appointment only in the math department, but the Corporation gave him that title.

Comment: @JeffE : You're mistaken.  I've revised my posting to clarify this.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's unclear. [http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Rota.html](Rota's MacTutor biography) says: _Rota was given the title Professor of Applied Mathematics at MIT but in 1972 his title was changed to Professor of Applied Mathematics and Philosophy._  [His _New York Times_ obituary](http://www.nytimes.com/1999/05/01/us/gian-carlo-rota-66-professor-of-mathematics-and-philosophy.html) says: _At M.I.T., Dr. Rota was the only professor of applied mathematics and philosophy, a **dual position** to which he was **appointed** in 1974._ (1/2)

Comment: Neither of these sources state explicitly that his title was honorary, and the _Times_ obit suggests he actually had a dual appointment.  What's your source? On the other hand, we was also the ["Norbert Wiener Professor of Mathematics"](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~cyan/Rota.html), which is clearly an honorary title. (2/2)

Comment: Rota's philosophy professorship was not honorary, but he was not considered a faculty member in MIT's Department of Linguistics and Philosophy either.

Comment: This is was what Rota himself told me about his appointment in philosophy:  His philosophy professorship was not honorary, but he was not considered a faculty member in MIT's Department of Linguistics and Philosophy either.  He taught classes in both mathematics and philosophy (his specialty in philosophy being Husserlian phenomenology), but he was not listed among the linguistics and philosophy faculty.  I asked him about this discrepancy, and he told me that the philosophy appointment was a something special he had been given, and he was independent of the regular philosophy department

Comment: The thing the in the *New York Times* obituary was cribbed from what I wrote in Rota's obituary in the MIT newspaper *The Tech*:  http://tech.mit.edu/V119/N21/21rota.21n.html  (The first draft had a more detailed statement about his joint appointment, but we cut it because it hardly seemed relevant.)

Comment: This is not about named or endowed chairs.  Those are things often created before it is known who the incumbents will be.  The question is about titles created just for one professor, based on what that professor individually has done.  With an endowed chair the appointment follows a rule rather than making a singular exception.

Comment: @MichaelHardy evidently the positions you are referring to are very rare indeed and seem to arise only in response to a whimsical or quirky wish on the part of a famous scientist. Considering this, do you have any special reason to expect that there is a noun associated with such positions?

Comment: @DanRomik : I don't know how rare they are.  As for a wish on the part of the appointee, I wonder if the wish came from those who appointed someone? It's not hard to imagine some authority granting the title of emeritus to Donald Knuth and deciding to give him a special custom-designed title.  But certainly I would not expect to see such a thing at most universities. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Emeritus [just means he is retired](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emeritus).

Comment: @DanRomik : QUOTE In some cases the term is conferred automatically upon all persons who retire at a given rank, but in others it remains a mark of distinguished service, awarded to only a few on retirement. END QUOTE

Comment: [It seems that](https://facultyaffairs.stanford.edu/retirement) at Stanford it is conferred automatically upon retirement.

Answer (score 6):

In the United States, these types of "one-off" titles are typically given as a stage of promotion beyond full professorship.  The typical generic name would be ["chaired professor," "distinguished professor," or "titled professor."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_ranks_in_the_United_States#Most_common_hierarchy)  This is a rank that many faculty never reach, and typically the highest rank that a professor can achieve in the university as a professor---any further "promotion" is actually a change of position into management, e.g., dean, provost, president.

Such positions often come with a set of funds dedicated to support them, giving the faculty promoted to the position additional freedom of operation.  Often the exact title is set by the person or organization that endows support for the position.  For example, my thesis advisor is the "Panasonic Professor of Electrical Engineering" at MIT, meaning that his particular "one-off" position was endowed by the Panasonic corporation.  Such ties, however, typically mean little besides the name.

Comment: But "chaired professor" and "distinguished professor" are not the same thing.  Some universities have a position called "Distinguished Professor", and that is something that exists under codified rules, sometimes specifying that only a small number of professors can hold that title at any time.  At some universities the title of "University Professor" is used.  At M.I.T., the title is "Institute Professor", and I think only 12 professors can have that title at any time.  Isadore Singer in the math department is one of those. That is not an uncodified title created for just one professor.

Comment: It's more than just the name, usually endowed chairs come with endowed chair funds for additional salary or research.  These can be quite considerable -- tens of thousands to low six digits more.

Comment: so your thesis advisor was Gerald Jay Sussman?

Comment: @darethas Indeed, as can be readily confirmed by anybody who feels like looking up my thesis. :-)